# How to store python output recieved in node js?

Tags: python, node.js, type-conversion, child-process

I'm invoking a python script from node js. The python script retrieves data from a REST API and stores it in a dataframe and then there's a search function based on user input. I'm confused as to what variable type does python send the data to node js in? I've tried to convert into a string but in node js it says it is an unresolved variable type. Here's the code:

````
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
nested = json.loads(r.text)
nested_full = json_normalize(nested)
req_data= json_normalize(nested,record_path ='items')
search = req_data.get(["name", "id"," ])
#search.head(10)



filter = sys.argv[1:]
print(filter)
input = filter[0]
print(input)
result = search[search["requestor_name"].str.contains(input)]
result = result.to_String(index=false)
response = '```' + str(result) + '```'
print(response)
sys.stdout.flush()
````

Here's the node js program that invokes the above python script. How do i store the output in a format which i can pass to another function in node?

```
var input = 'robert';
var childProcess = require("child_process").spawn('python', ['./search.py', input], {stdio: 'inherit'})
const stream = require('stream');
const format = require('string-format')


childProcess.on('data', function(data){
    process.stdout.write("python script output",data)

    result += String(data);
    console.log("Here it is", data);

});
childProcess.on('close', function(code) {
        if ( code === 1 ){
            process.stderr.write("error occured",code);

            process.exit(1);
        }
        else{
            process.stdout.write('done');

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```
childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```